# How to sync data with angular-data

Tags: angularjs, angular-data

I have a angular project with a angular-data to work with my Restful API.

my situation is as following:

in my service I return a defineresource
in my controller I use service.defineresource.findAll().then

it all works fine but here is my question. when new data is added to the server how do I update the cache or add the new data to my cache.

Please advice

code:
//in service.js

```
    .factory('Service', function(DS) {
     DS.defineresource({
        name: 'items'
        endpoint:'api/v2/users'
      });
     });
```

//in controller.js

```
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Service) {
      Service.findAll().then(function (data) {
        $scope.items = data
      });

   });
```

my code is above fetches all the data when I load it first time, but after the initial loading it only loads from the cache. My question is there a way to sync and fetch new data without destroying the cache.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to update the grid when some other user adds data to the server? As in 3-way data binding?

Comment: Yes, I want to update my UI when data changes in my web server either by clicking refresh button or auto refresh every lets say 15 min

Comment: You would use ng-click to then call your service to fetch the data gain. This would then be set to the scope property again. For every 15 mins refresh you would use $timeout to call your service and then update the scope property.

Comment: My question is how do i fetch new data from my server when I do when i use findAll() it fetches data from the cache and doesn't fetch from server

Comment: Can you please show your code for your service. I'm not familar with what a defineresouce is.

Comment: I have updated it above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force the refresh of the data from the backend you need to set `bypassCache: true` in the options. If you don't pass this then angular-data will load from cache. This is documented in the [api documentation.](http://angular-data.pseudobry.com/documentation/api/angular-data/DS.async%20methods_findAll)

To refresh the data every 15 minutes use `$timeout` with 900000 milliseconds. To have a button to refresh use a scope function that will be called from a `ng-click` on a button.

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, Service) {
    $scope.refreshData = function () {
        Service.findAll({}, { bypassCache: true }).then(function (data) {
            $scope.items = data;
        });
    }

    $scope.refreshData();

    $timeout($scope.refreshData, 900000);
});
```

```
<button ng-click="refreshData()">Refresh</button>
```

Comment: okay thanks, however I am not able to visualise any changes when findAll. Do know whether I have to reorder or maybe call digest ? to update the UI ? with the change ?

Comment: What do you mean by visualise? What are you using to display? ng-repeat?

Comment: yes i am using ng-repeat service.findAll() only reads from server the first time and the following times just from the catch

Answer (score -1):

If you are using only Angular Routes, Use :

```
$route.reload()
```

it will reload / refresh your page . so the data will be sync . 
you can use it in ng-click or check in your controller when new data is entered use it

```
  $route.reload()
```

if you are using UI-Router  you can do the same but instead of $route.reload() use this :

```
$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
```

Comment: even with this implementation its not asyncing with the server.